# openstack controller nodes deployed on virtual machine

Tags: controller, virtual-machine, openstack

I want to deploy an openstack that put my controller nodes on virtual machine while compute nodes on physical server to get HA. But I couldn't understand which service or compononts should be installed on vm. I think glance, database ,rabbitmq and so on are likely to be installed on vm. And nova-compute should be deployed on physical server. Anyone else can tell me the detail? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy services nova, keystone, glance, neutron, cinder etc on controller nodes i.e., vm

Deploy nova-compute, neutron agent, rabbitmq on compute nodes

Comment: I am not sure if you can install neutron on a Virtual Machine and even if you can I assume that the configuration of networking will be very difficult.